# convert a 3d point from camera space to object space, in c++ with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

In computer vision, when I need to convert a cv::mat from object(world) space coordinates to camera space, or a camera-centric coordinate, i use the following
code: ( where `rvec` and `tvec` are the rotation and translation vectors of the camera)

```
cv::Mat R; //holds rotation matrix
cv::Rodrigues(rvec, R); // converts a rotation vector to a 3x3 matrix
R = R.t();  // rotation of inverse
tvec2 = -R * tvec; // translation of inverse
```

giving me `tvec2` as the camera space coordinate.

My current problem is the opposite. I have an array of 3d points in camera space, and i need to convert them to world space. What does the inverse of the above function look like?

Thank you.

Comment: in your above function you don't show how to transform the points (the actual operation). Inverse should be easy to compute if you provide that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would advice you to do is have a 4x4 projection matrix. Indeed, it would be way easier for you to transform your points from the World Cordinate System (WCS) to you Camera Coordinate System. Indeed, let's say you have a point in WCS at {0,0,0}, and your camera at {10, 0, 0} with a rotation on Y axis of 45 degree. What you can do is create your projection matrix like that

rot = 45 degrees = 0,785398 rad.

Rotation: (3x3)

[image]

Translation: (1x3)

[image]

Your projection Matrix will be: (4x4)

[image]

With the projection matrix, let's say you have a point in you WCS at:

[image]

just change it to a point at:

[image]

then what you can do to change it to you CCS is:

```
PointInCCS = projectionMatrix * PointInWCS;
```

to return in WCS just use the matrix inverse:

```
PointInWCS = projectionMatrix.inv() * PointInCCS;
```

Comment: Thank you! i will try this.